# Populate DataGrid in WPF with Dictionary items

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, datagrid

I have a `Dictionary` that has `PointCoordinate` objects as values.

```
Dictionary<string, PointCoordinate> PointCoordinates;
```

My `PointCoordinate` class is defined as below:

```
class PointCoordinate
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}
```

How can I populate a `DataGrid` in `WPF` with `Keys` and `X`, `Y` properties of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Windows;

    namespace WpfApplication1 {

        public class PointCoordinate {
            public double X { get; set; }
            public double Y { get; set; }
        }

        public class PointCoordinate2 : PointCoordinate {
            public string key { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class MainWindow : Window {
            public MainWindow() {
                InitializeComponent();

                Dictionary<string, PointCoordinate> PointCoordinates = new Dictionary<string, PointCoordinate>();
                PointCoordinates.Add("Number 1", new PointCoordinate() { X = 1, Y = 4 });
                PointCoordinates.Add("Number 2", new PointCoordinate() {X = 2, Y = 5});
                PointCoordinates.Add("Number 3", new PointCoordinate() {X = 3, Y = 6});

                List<PointCoordinate2> lList = new List<PointCoordinate2>();
                foreach (var lItem in PointCoordinates) {
                    PointCoordinate2 lPC2 = new PointCoordinate2();
                    lPC2.key = lItem.Key;
                    lPC2.X = lItem.Value.X;
                    lPC2.Y = lItem.Value.Y;
                    lList.Add(lPC2);
                }
                //var n = from x in PointCoordinates select ;
                myDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                myDataGrid.ItemsSource = lList;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is not Databinding to the original data. Nevertheless it does display the data properly. More on Data Binding here: http://csharphardcoreprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/02/20/data-binding-part-1-advanced-wpf/